# NextJS: function exported is and imported correctly inside src/util but getting undefined

Tags: express, next.js

```
**npsUtil.js**
const { getRetirementYear } = require('./ppfUtil');
**ppfUtil.js**
const getRetirementYear = (dateOfBirth, retirementAge) => {
  const birthDate = moment(dateOfBirth);
  const birthYear = birthDate.year();
  const retirementYear = birthYear + +retirementAge;
  return retirementYear;
};

module.exports = {
  getRetirementYear
}
```

inside npsUtil getRetirementYear is getting TypeError: getRetirementYear is not a function.

I tried changing the paths and adding the file extension but nothing from the above works. I was expecting to work just fine.

Comment: Can you show the full error from Next.js?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8blbx.png @RobinThomas

Comment: Can you add the full contents of both files `npsUtil.js` and `ppfUtil.js` to the question?